# Function inside loop wont run

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I've been bashing my head against this wall I am completely new to JavaScript coming from c#
and  I am completely baffled for my class I have to smooth out a simple code we made to count down from zero by making it into a loop and for the life of me I just cant get it to work

```js
var i = 10;
var timeout = 10000;
var x = 10
if (i == 5) {
  alert("help me")
}

while (i > 0) {
  //10
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = i;
    i = i - 1;
  }, timeout);
  timeout = timeout - 1000;
}
```

Comment: Count down "to" zero, presumably, not count down from zero.

Comment: You can't do this in a loop, `setTimeout()` is asynchronous, and it doesn't wait for the timeouts.

Comment: Try: `while (timeout > 0)` instead of `while (i > 0)`

Comment: The `setTimeout` callback will be called *after* the timeout. The `while` loop does *not wait* for that. So `i` is decremented *sometime later* and will not affect the `while` loop condition *right now* in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchrony in JavaScript is a rather involved subject.

Traditional loops (`for`, `while`, `do..while`, `for..of`) are synchronous, and so cannot help you reach your goal here.

To do what you want, you can use indirect recursion like so:

```js
const countdown = (from = 10, to = 0, interval = 1000, cb = console.log) => {
  if(from < 0) return
   
  cb(from)
  setTimeout(() => 
    countdown(--from), interval)
}

countdown()
```

There is also a more modern approach that enables the use of syntax that looks a bit more familiar. This approach uses `for await... of`, the syntax for which does not appear to be supported by StackOverflow's transpiler:

```
const delay = (interval) => new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(resolve, interval))

async function* countdown(from = 10, to = 0, interval = 1000) {
  for(;from >= 0; from--) {
    yield from
    await delay(interval)
  }
}

for await(let count of countdown()) {
  console.log(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is what you're looking for to execute a function every certain amount of time:

```
let i = 10;
let interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = i;
    i--;
    if(i < 0) clearInterval(interval);//Clear the interval when complete
}, 1000);//Every 1000 ms = every second
```

Answer (score -2):

The code below will countdown to zero.

```
var i = 10;
while (i > 0){
   i--;
   console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to wait 1 second between each number in the countdown.